# Python multiprocessing.Manager and os.fork producing strange behavior

Tags: python, multiprocessing, fork

My coworker asked for my help with a problem he was having with a daemon script he is working on. He was having a strange error involving a multiprocessing.Manager, which I managed to reproduce with the following five lines:

```
import multiprocessing, os, sys
mgr = multiprocessing.Manager()
pid = os.fork()
if pid > 0:
    sys.exit(0)
```

When run on CentOS 6 Linux and Python 2.6, I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.6/multiprocessing/util.py", line 235, in _run_finalizers
    finalizer()
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.6/multiprocessing/util.py", line 174, in __call__
    res = self._callback(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.6/multiprocessing/managers.py", line 576, in _finalize_manager
    if process.is_alive():
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.6/multiprocessing/process.py", line 129, in is_alive
    assert self._parent_pid == os.getpid(), 'can only test a child process'
AssertionError: can only test a child process
Error in atexit._run_exitfuncs:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.6/atexit.py", line 24, in _run_exitfuncs
    func(*targs, **kargs)
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.6/multiprocessing/util.py", line 269, in _exit_function
    p.join()
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.6/multiprocessing/process.py", line 117, in join
    assert self._parent_pid == os.getpid(), 'can only join a child process'
AssertionError: can only join a child process
Error in sys.exitfunc:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.6/atexit.py", line 24, in _run_exitfuncs
    func(*targs, **kargs)
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.6/multiprocessing/util.py", line 269, in _exit_function
    p.join()
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.6/multiprocessing/process.py", line 117, in join
    assert self._parent_pid == os.getpid(), 'can only join a child process'
AssertionError: can only join a child process
```

I suspect the error is due to some interaction between os.fork and the multiprocessing.Manager, and that he should use the multiprocessing module to create new processes instead of os.fork. Can anyone confirm this and/or explain what is going on? If my hunch is correct, why is this the wrong place to use os.fork?

Comment: The `Manager` always creates a new process that handles the shared memory so there seems to be some interaction. Right now I'm not able to tell you exactly why this happens and how to fix this using `os.fork`. I must agree that using `os.fork` should be avoided since it is really *low level*. There must be some way of using `multiprocessing` instead.

Answer (score 3):

The issue is that `Manager` create a process and try to stop it at `sys.exit`. Since the memory of the process is copied (lazily) during the fork both the parent and the child try to stop the process and wait for it to stop. However, as the exception mention only the parent process can do that. If instead of using `os.fork`, you use `multiprocessing.Process` which will spawn a new process which wouldn't try to close the `Manager` at `sys.exit`.